# Why is my object greyed out in the UV Editing Tab?

Tags: objects, shortcut, color

so I started using Blender yesterday and made some objects.
But now I accidentally pressed a shortcut I think and my objects are all greyed out in the UV Editing Tab.

Greyed out Object:
[image]

In The Shading Tab it still shows the color of the object:
[image]

Does someon know what I pressed or what I changed that the objects are now greyed out in the UV Editing Tab?
I tried to use Strg + z to revert it but it didnt work.

Comment: UV editing tab uses _Solid Preview Mode_ by default (Shading Tab uses _Material Preview_). Either press Z when the mouse is in the 3D viewport and select _material preview_ or _rendered_ from the pie menu that appears, or choose it from the 4 little circles in the top right of the viewport (the 2 farthest to the right are "material preview" and "rendered", respectively). My guess is you pressed _Shift+Z_ (wireframe toggle) by mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats exactly what I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3D view is currently in wireframe mode (1). Click on the white globe (2) to select solid view or press <kbd>Z</kbd> and select <kbd>Solid</kbd> from the Pie menu.

[image]